# MS-SQL and PHP.INI - how to enable mssql support in PHP in IIS7

Tags: php, sql-server, iis-7, php-ini

Currently, we are running PHP on Windows IIS7. And the relevant section from the php.ini reports this to me;

```
Configure Command   ....  "--without-mssql" "--without-pdo-mssql" ....
```

Clearly, this PHP lacks the mssql support.

What does it take for the `--without-mssql` phrase to disappear from the configure area and thus the support for mssql is present in the php compile?

So far, this is what we have done.

we enabled the php_mssql.dll as a php extension.
we made sure that ntwdb.dll is in the same folder as php

Our show stops with this fataller!

`Fatal error: Call to undefined function mssql_connect() in ...`

Answer (score 1):

extension=php_mssql.dll

Php Manuel php.ini Config (install mssql) document.

http://php.net/manual/en/mssql.installation.php