# Trouble using MsSQL with PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, windows, iis-7

I am debating between using MsSQL and SQLSrv to connect to SQL Server.

Our platform is running IIS7 on Windows and using PHP. We tried using the `MsSQL` extension to work but had problems so we decided to use `SQLSrv` instead since it was easier to get working.

Using `MsSQL` would be the preferred option because it fits the workflow better and the function names are similar to the ones used in SQL. Is it worth the effort to use `MsSQL` with PHP in light of the problems we are facing or should we use `SQLSrv` with the downsides mentioned.

Also, on the [MSDN Docs for SQLSrv](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296189.aspx) it mentions that the documentation is for preview and might change. Does that mean the functions could end up changing?

Comment: Hey, I edited your question since it was a little unfocused. I hope that's alright with you. Can you post the error you were having with MsSQL? Maybe I can help you get that working.

Comment: much better! Well, there are no errors so far...  I got irritated when I saw sqlsrv_num_rows return false - just because the cursor type is not set right! with mysql/mssql num_rows the thing just works... no need to worry about the cursors!

Comment: why do you think we have two options... why not just mssql_connect? why sqlsrv_connect too? what's the diff? is one better the other? when do you choose one over the other?

Comment: SQLSrv is a procedural interface and MsSQL uses PHP's PDO functions so its more like normal SQL. If you use PDO then use mssql_connect.

Comment: I do want to use mssql functions as opposed to sqlsrv... but unfortunately, we could not, and [that's another story](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9106636/ms-sql-and-php-ini-how-to-enable-mssql-support-in-php-in-iis7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as the notice on the documentation all it means is they may change the wording of the document later in its release, I can't promise that the functions will stay the same however nothing on that page leads me to believe otherwise. Here is a Microsoft Wiki article on [Accessing SQL Server Databases from PHP](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/accessing-sql-server-databases-from-php.aspx) is says that the process outlined on that page is compatible with SQL Server 2005, SQL Server 2008, and SQL Server 2008 R2 so the software should not change since it needs to maintain compatibility with older versions of SQL Server.

You may also want to reference that wiki article, it contains step by step setup procedures for MsSQL and SQLSrv which may work for you and fix the issue you have.